# Translate animation is behind other components

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, translate-animation

I have layout which consists of image parts shown below.I just want to set all image resources with translate animation that starts from bottom part.When do this, animation is starting behind of other image layouts.I just searched for a solution,but no solution found.

```
android:clipChildren="false";   
yourLayout.bringToFront();   
setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
```

All of the above solutions didn't work for me.Someone can help me ?

My xml code to create image button is

```
 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bck_game_image"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bos">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buton0"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"></ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
.....
</TableRow>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your xml code

Comment: Be more specific. I don't understand your question. Which of your layouts do you want to animate? You can do it easily with Java Code.

Comment: I am animating ImageButton in above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using yourLayout.bringToFront(), use the following lines of code:-

```
linearLayout.bringChildToFront(imageView);
linearLayout.requestLayout();
linearLayout.invalidate();
```

Comment: It works,but index of the image button is changing after above lines of code.For example i set the animation for upper left most image button,but ,it affects upper right most image button.

Comment: by index, you mean the ID of ImageButton? or something else ?

Comment: When i used the code you specified,animation is effecting another image button,not the one i target.I think the position of the image button is changing.

Comment: Please post your animation code. Update your question and add it there.